# Same noun, same case, same adjective, different ending – what are the rules behind this?

Tags: adjective, declension, adjective-ending

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *[Warum „anderen“ anstatt „anderem“?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33874)*

Adjective endings in German seem inconsistent, even if one is aware that adjective endings depend on case, gender and number.

For example:

> Ein **roter** Apfel liegt auf dem Tisch.
>   Der **rote** Apfel liegt auf dem Tisch.
>   Der Apfel ist **rot**.

In all three sentences, the same adjective *(rot)* describes the same noun *(Apfel),* which has the same case (nominative). Still, the adjective has different endings.

How is this phenomenon called and what are the rules behind it?

---

<sup>This is an attempt to create a canonical question to serve as duplicate for all similar questions. Answers should therefore not only focus on the example but be capable to address all similar questions. For further details, see [this post](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/989/2594) on Meta.</sup>

Answer (score 31, accepted):

*TL;DR: Adjectives have to be declined not only according to the noun’s gender, number, and case but also **according to the type of article** used. If a verb links the adjective to the subject, the adjective is not declined at all.*

### Definite and indefinite articles

Using the German language, we differentiate between **definite articles** (bestimmte Artikel) and **indefinite articles**  (unbestimmte Artikel)

Definite articles include:

> this, these, that, those (English),
> dieser, diese, dieses, jener, jene, jenes (German)

Indefinite articles (for our purposes) include:

> a, many, few (English)
> ein, eine, keiner, keine (German)

I will presume the distinctions between these two groups and their respective usages are understood.

### Case 1 (weak declension)

When we use a **definite article** with a noun that we want to describe with an adjective, the adjective has to be declined according to the gender, number, and case of the noun:

> Der rote Apfel liegt auf dem Tisch. (nominative, masculine, singular)

> Ich sehe den roten Apfel. (accusative, masculine, singular)

> Ich sehe die rote Tomate. (accusative, feminine, singular)

> Ich sehe die roten Tomaten. (accusative, plural)

> Ich sehe das rote Haus. (accusative, neutral)

(There is no distinction between genders in plural.)

### Case 2 (strong declension)

When there is **no article** in front of the noun that we want to describe with an adjective, the adjective has to be declined according to the gender, number, and case of the noun as well, but in some cases (marked bold) the declension differs from the weak declension. This form is usually used with plural words and words that rarely or never appear in the plural ([Singulariatantum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularetantum)), such as *Wein (vine)*:

> **Roter** Käse liegt auf dem Tisch. (nominative, masculine, singular)

> Ich sehe roten Wein. (accusative, masculine, singular)

> Ich sehe rote Milch. (accusative, feminine, singular)

> Ich sehe **rote** Tomaten. (accusative, plural)

> Ich sehe **rotes** Gemüse. (accusative, neutral)

The strong declension is called such because endings differ most often between genders, cases, and numbers.

### Case 3 (mixed declension)

When we use an **indefinite article** with a noun that we want to describe with an adjective, the adjective has to be declined in yet another way. However, the declension always corresponds to either the weak or the strong declension (hence “mixed”):

> Ein roter Apfel liegt auf dem Tisch. (nominative, masculine, singular)

> Ich sehe einen roten Apfel. (accusative, masculine, singular)

> Ich sehe eine rote Tomate. (accusative, feminine, singular)

> Ich sehe keine roten Tomaten. (accusative, plural)

> Ich sehe ein rotes Haus. (accusative, neutral)

### Case 4 (predicative)

When we use a **verb to link** the noun to the adjective, we exclusively use the adjective’s base. No declension is needed:

> Der Apfel ist rot.

> Der Apfel schmeckt gut.

> Er malte das Haus rot an.

---

More information and word tables can be found [here](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/adjektive/deklination) in German or [here](https://www.germanveryeasy.com/adjective-declension) in English.

Comment: Great answer, +1 for the tl;dr. Adjective endings depend on 24 different combinations, [specific, non-specific] x [masculine, feminine, neutral, plural] x [nominative, accusative, dative]

Comment: And then there is case 5 where the attribute has fused into the noun, _Rotwein_.

Comment: "TL;DR: Adjectives have to be declined according to the noun's gender, the case, and the type of article used" ... and what about number? While @YuvalHerziger above seems to do so, it feels incorrect to me to count "plural" as another "gender".

Comment: @YuvalHerziger: What do you mean by "[specific, non-specific]"? Note that the answer correctly distinguishes *three* modes of article use. Also, why is genitive missing from your list of cases? I count 3 x 4 x 3 x 2 = 72 different combinations (and that is still excluding the uninflected form).

Comment: Und Dativ? Dem rote(n?/m?) Apfel?

Comment: That made it even more complicated!!

Answer (score 8):

In 1 *der rote Apfel* the gender of *Apfel* is expressed by *der*. After *der/die/das* the adjective does not need a gender marker and the ending is only *-e*.

In 2 *ein Apfel* you can’t see the gender because *ein* has dropped the endings *-er/-es*. That is why the gender marker *-er* goes to the adjective and we say *ein roter Apfel*.

In 3 you have *rot* as a **predicative adjective**. In this position the adjective never has an ending.

In German there are article words with the gender endings *-er/-es* such as
*der, dieser, jener, welcher* etc. After these article words the adjective has no gender endings, but only the endings *-e/-en*. This declension is called **weak declension**.

The second group of article words has dropped the gender markers *-er/-es* such as *ein, mein, dein* etc. Now the adjective takes on the task to mark the gender (**strong adjective declension**).

Comment: Simple, yet easy to understand, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative answer that does away with "mixed declension" and reference to definite or indefinite articles. This answer deals with **attributive adjectives**, i.e. those modifying a noun, since **predicative** and **adverbial** adjectives bear no endings.

> Das hast du aber **schön** gesagt. (adverbial adjective)
> Wir finden den Vorschlag nicht **gut**. (predicative adjective)

## Basic Rules

Adjectives have two sets of endings: **strong** and **weak**.

1. The adjective bears a **strong** ending when it is not preceded by a determiner, or when the determiner preceding it bears no ending. Note hat prenominal genitives behave like a determiner without an ending.

> Ø kühl**es** Bier, ein-Ø kühl**es** Bier
> Ø schön**e** Blumen, welch-Ø schön**e** Blumen
> mit Ø neu**em** Design, mit manch-Ø neu**em** Service
> Merkels Ø jüngst**er** Vorschlag

2. The adjective bears a **weak** ending when it is preceded by a determiner bearing an ending.

> dies*es* kühl**e** Bier
> welch*e* schön**en** Blumen
> mit manch*em* neu**en** Service
> d*er* jüngst**e** Vorschlag Merkels

3. The **strong** endings of adjectives are identical to the endings of determiners (*pronominale Flexion*: *dies-er, jen-es, jed-e, welch-e, ...*), with the exception of the genitive singular masculine and neuter, where the adjective has *-en* instead of *-es*.

> jen**er** Vorschlag = gut**er** Vorschlag
> welch**es** Brot = frisch**es** Brot
>
> aufgrund dies**es** Problems ≠ aufgrund defekt**en** Materials

4. The **weak** ending is *-e* in the nominative singular only and *-en* otherwise. (Note that, outside of the masculine singular, nominative and accusative are always identical, so that the accusative singular neuter and feminine also has *-e*).

> dieser/dieses/diese klug**e** Mann/Kind/Frau
>
> diesen klug**en** Mann
> diese klug**en** Menschen
> mit diesem/diesem/dieser/diesen klug**en** Mann/Kind/Frau/Menschen

5. Multiple adjectives modifying the same noun bear the same ending.

> das umfangreich**e** technisch**e** Equipment
> umfangreich**es** technisch**es** Equipment
>
> *but:* eine **gut** gewählte Analogie (*gut* modifies *gewählte*, not *Analogie*)

Note that rules 1 and 2 reference **inflected word forms** and not words (lexemes). In German, certain determiners (such as the the indefinite article *ein*, the negative determiner *kein* and the possessive determiners *mein, dein, ...*) have no ending in the nominative singular masculine and neuter. When they have no ending, they fall under rule 1 (*ein kühles Bier*); when they have one, they fall under rule 2 (*mit einem kühlen Bier*).

## Adjective or Determiner?

Beware of homonyms such as the following.

> mit **einem** einzigen Punkt (indefinite article)
> mit dem **einen** Punkt (numeral adjective)
>
> **beide** neuen Modelle (determiner, triggers weak inflection)
> die **beiden** neuen Modelle (adjective, bears weak inflection)

Note that *viel-, ander-* are adjectives.

> viel**e** klug**e** Vorschläge, ein ander**er** Betroffen**er** (strong by rule 1)
> die viel**en** klug**en** Vorschläge, der ander**e** Betroffen**e** (weak by rule 2)

## Deviations from Basic Rules

In the dative singular masculine and neuter, *-m* is often replaced by *-n* on adjectives following an adjective ending in *-m*, counter to rule 5.

> mit umfangreichem technisch**en** Equipment

A violation of the basic rules regularly occurs in appositions with *wir*.

> wir Deutsch**en**, wir beid**en** (weak, unexpected)
> wir Deutsch**e**, wir beid**e** (strong, as expected)

The words *folgend-* and *sämtlich-* sometimes show unexpected strong inflection.

> **folgendes** gesellschaftliche Problem (determiner triggering weak inflection)
> das **folgende** gesellschaftliche Problem (adjective)
> folgendes groß**es** Problem (unexpected strong inflection; expected *große*)
>
> sämtliche anwesend**e** Bürger (unexpected strong inflection; expected *anwesenden*)

In certain fixed expressions or old-fashioned speech, endings may be dropped.

> auf **gut** Glück
> Ein **garstig** Lied! Pfui! ein **politisch** Lied! Ein **leidig** Lied! (Goethe)

## Declension Table

|  | masc. | neut. | fem. | pl. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| n. | -er -e | -es -e | -e -e | -e -en |
| a. | -en -en | -es -e | -e -e | -e -en |
| d. | -em -en | -em -en | -er -en | -en -en |
| g. | -en -en | -en -en | -er -en | -er -en |

- Left forms are strong, right forms are weak.
- Observe how the strong forms are identical to those of determiners such as *dies-er*, with the exception of the genitive singular masculine and neuter.
- Observe how the weak forms have *-e* in the nominative singular (and accusative singular neuter and feminine) and *-en* elsewhere.

## Terminology

- The term **determiner** is used instead of *article* to emphasize that these rules not only apply to definite and indefinite articles (*der, ein, ...*), but also words such as *alle, jeder, welchen, keinem, ihres, ...*
- The terms **strong** and **weak** have been used as far back as Jacob Grimm's *Deutsche Grammatik* (1822) ([source](http://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/book/view/grimm_grammatik01_1822?p=623)).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Ein roter Apfel liegt auf dem Tisch.
> 2. Der rote Apfel liegt auf dem Tisch.
> 3. Der Apfel ist rot.

Das letzte Beispiel „Der Apfel ist rot“ gehört nicht zu den ersten beiden Beispielen. Es ist eine Farbenangabe eines Artikels (*Prädikat*), nicht ein Eigenschaftswort (*Attribut*) des Apfels.

In den beiden ersten Fällen, *Apfel* ist maskulin „ein roter Apfel“ das ‚r‘ beschreibt einen maskulinen Artikel. 
In „Der rote Apfel liegt auf dem Tisch“ ist das ‚r‘ bereits im Artikel vorhanden und ist dann im Eigenschaftswort nicht mehr nötig.

Comment: "bereits im Artikel vorhanden" - das mag eine gute Eselsbrücke für diesen Fall sein, aber es taugt leider nicht als generelle Erklärung. In "Ich lege den roten Apfel auf den Tisch." ist das "n" schließlich auch "bereits im Artikel vorhanden", muss aber dennoch auch zu "roten" hinzugefügt werden.

Comment: Es scheint, dass die Adjektivendungen auf -r, -s und -m sich abschwächen zu Endungen auf -e und -en, insoweit der Artikel bereits auf einen der Konsonanten endet.

Comment: *Das letzte Beispiel „Der Apfel ist rot“ gehört nicht zu den ersten beiden Beispielen.* – Beachte, dass dieses Beispiel durchaus relevant ist, da zum Beispiel im Französischen prädikative Adjektive durchaus gemäß des zugehörigen Nomens dekliniert werden, z. B.: *La fille est petite. – Le garçon es petit. – Les garçons sont petites.*