# Deklination ohne Artikel

Tags: grammatical-case, declension

Can someone give me resources to learn about the  "Deklination ohne Artikel"?

There is for example this blog, but it doesn't help a lot:

[Die Deklination des Adjektivs ohne Artikel](http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/adjektiv/deklination-adjektiv-ohne-artikel/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are referring to *strong inflection / declension*. There is a nice [page on canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Stark.html?lang=en) about it. If your focus is on comparing it with the other declension types for adjectives, you might also want to check out:

[Same noun, same case, same adjective, different ending – what are the rules behind this?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25357/same-noun-same-case-same-adjective-different-ending-what-are-the-rules-behi)