# Syntax of “Immer das passende Geschenk!”

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, grammatical-case

I have a flyer in my hand. Its main slogan, very big and opulent, is the sentence:

> Immer das pasende Geschenk!

[image: Immer das pasende Geschenk!]

I’ve tried to figure out its grammar but I’ve got stuck in the middle.

- Why the termination for the adjective *passend* is *e,* while that *das* suggests that *Geschenk* is neutral (and it is)?
- Where is the verb?
- What mode is this? It has an exclamation mark but is not imperative.

This sentence seems to violate everything I’ve learned about sentences. What is happening here (syntactically)?

Comment: It is just an ellipsis as you will often see it in slogans or ads. The complete sentence could be, for example "Finden Sie immer das passende Geschenk" or "Immer das passende Geschenk kaufen".

Comment: Than why `das passende Geschenk`? Note the __das__ and the passend__e__

Comment: *Geschenk* is neuter and -e is the correct adjective suffix for the definite nominative or accusative case (just like *das große Haus*)

Comment: It’s not a full sentence because it doesn’t have a full verb.

Comment: The canonical question abiut strong and weak adjective declension: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25357/same-noun-same-case-same-adjective-different-ending-what-are-the-rules-behi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few possibilities for how these ellipses could be completed:

- Finden Sie immer das passende Geschenk! *(accusative)*
- Wir finden immer das passende Geschenk! *(accusative)*
- Immer das passende Geschenk finden Sie bei uns!  *(accusative)*
- Auf Sie wartet immer das passende Geschenk! *(nominative)*

Both the nominative and accusative cases imply the suffix -e on adjectives referring to *das Geschenk*.

Comment: Ich finde die Satzstellung hier klingt seltsam: _"Immer das passende Geschenk finden Sie bei uns!"_ Besser wäre meiner Ansicht nach: _"Bei uns finden Sie immer das passende Geschenk."_

Comment: The accusative is unlikely. Replace "Geschenk" by some masculine noun, say "Anzug", and you see that the slogan *"Immer der passende Anzug!" (nom.)*  looks a lot more idiomatic than *"Immer den passenden Anzug!" (acc.)*

Answer (score 2):

It is normal to put an "e" as termination for the adjective in front of a neutral noun.
for example:

```
Das verletzte Kind
Das grosse Haus
Das schöne Wetter
```

and so on.

There is no verb because it is a slogan.

Comment: Your statement about declension is too general, as you will find when considering _ein verletztes Kind_ etc.