# How to make a noun indefinite?

Tags: article

When we use a name with its article then it is definite, I cannot make the following sentence more general. I’m trying refer to all children in the world. And why do we use the pronoun *es* in such sentences? Is my second sample also correct?

> Die Frau in meinem Büro kann es nicht ertragen Kinder.
>
> Die Frau in meinem Büro kann Kinder nicht ertragen.

And in the following example why is *-es* droped, shouldn’t it be: *meines Kind* because *Kind* is neuter?

> Ich kann mein Kind nicht mehr ertragen.

Comment: The first sentence is ungrammatical. Only the second and third are correct. Regarding _meines Kind_, that form doesn’t exist; look it up in a declension table.

Comment: The third example is basically a separate question dealing with declension; almost covered by [this question](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/25357/15318) and certainly by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is rather simple: To make *definite* references, use the *definite* article. For *indefinite* references, use the *indefinite* article in the singular or *no article* in plural.

Let’s strip your examples of everything unnecessary:

> Sie erträgt *Kinder* nicht.

This one has no article, so it generally means she cannot stand children.

> Sie erträgt *die* Kinder nicht.

She only cannot stand *these* (previously established or clear by context) children.

Moving to singular:

> Sie erträgt *ein* Kind nicht.

Simply *Kind* would be wrong, and the sentence altogether is weird, because why would you only not stand *one* child?

> Sie erträgt *das* Kind nicht.

She cannot stand *the* child (clear by context or previously established).

Of course, further context can be given with adjectives if desired:

> Sie erträgt *schreiende* Kinder nicht.
> Sie erträgt *ein schreiendes* Kind nicht.
>
> Sie erträgt *die schreienden* Kinder nicht.
> Sie erträgt *das schreiende* Kind nicht.

(Here the indefinite singular does not sound as bad as above.)

Comment: Jan, could we say _sie ertraegt neues Kind nicht?_

Comment: @Bergmann try reading my answer again. (Hint: no, it’s lacking something.)

Comment: Deine Freundin, die kann blasen, die kann blasen, blasen, blasen, die kann blasen blasen blasen an den Füssen nicht ertragen :)

Comment: @WayneEra Knapp an der Offensive-Flagge vorbeigeschrammt ô.o

Comment: @jan ist von einem lied von SDP, ist mir wegen dem "nicht ertragen" wieder in den sinn gekommen...soviel spass muss doch sein ^^

Comment: @WayneEra Kenn i ned … wohl deswegen drum ;)

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence doesn't make sense at all. One *might* understand it as

> Hey kids, the woman at my office can't stand it.

But in German, there'd be a comma missing before "Kinder"...

The second sentence is fully correct. It means:

> The woman at my office can not stand children.

The "es" in "kann es ertragen" is only required if there's no closer description of the required accusative object. For example:

> Ich kann das Wetter nicht ertragen. (No *es* here, as *das Wetter* is the accusative object)

as opposed to.

> Wie findest Du das Wetter? Ich kann es nicht ertragen. (*es* stands for *das Wetter* here and is the accusative object)

The last sentence is really a matter of understanding the accusative case:

```
Nominativ: mein Kind
Genitiv:   meines Kindes
Dativ:     meinem Kind
Akkusativ: mein Kind
```

> Ich kann [wen oder was, Akkusativ] nicht ertragen.
>   Ich kann mein Kind nicht ertragen.

Comment: But we could say i think. "ich kann neues Kind nicht ertragen" so here _es_  places

Comment: @Bergmann "Ich kann **das neue** Kind nicht ertragen", if you'd like to say that you cannot stand the new kid. Or if it is a random kid, then "ein neues Kind"; or if many kids, then "die neuen Kinder"; or if generally all new kids, then "neue Kinder". These are the four options that I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: @Bergmann No, you can not put it this way. In addition to what Em1 said in his comment, if you want to say you can not stand newborns in general, you'd have to say *Ich kann neugeborene Kinder nicht ertragen* (again, watch the acc. pl.). In singular you always need the indefinite article, while in plural you must omit it. Example: *Ich kann ein neugeborenes Kind nicht ertragen* vs. *Ich kann neugeborene Kinder nicht ertragen*, but *Ich kann das Nachbarskind nicht ertragen.* vs. *Ich kann die Nachbarskinder nicht ertragen.*

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, with "neues Kind" i meant "the new child" suppose "the new child in our classroom"

Comment: @Bergmann Then you need the definite article anyway.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar,When there is no article how could the adjectives be declinated? Z.B.: neues Kind, roten Stuhl etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your examples 2 and 3 are correct, 1 is wrong. A legal example similar to example 1 would be:

> Die Frau kann es nicht ertragen, Kinder um sich zu haben.

*Meines* would only be valid in genitive singular, like:

> Der Mantel meines Kindes ist verschwunden.