# Was ist richtig: „viele anderen Fragen“ oder „viele andere Fragen“?

Tags: grammar, adjective, grammatical-case

Was ist korrekt:

> viele anderen Fragen

oder

> viele andere Fragen

?

Es handelt sich dabei um folgenden Satz:

> Es stehen noch viele andere Fragen offen.

Ich habe sowohl im Internet, als auch auf dieser Webseite nach einer Antwort gesucht, bevor ich diese Frage gestellt habe (ich habe mein Grammatikbuch nicht dabei). Allerdings es gibt in der deutschen Sprache einige Ausnahmen, die ich nicht wie manche Leute hier alle kenne und ich wollte daher mittels dieser Frage sicherstellen, welche Version richtig ist.

Ich habe u.a. folgende Information, laut der die Flexion zweier Adjektive doch einige Ausnahmen zu haben scheint, gefunden: 
[Flexion zweier Adjektive in der Nominalgruppe](http://goo.gl/nL1cHJ). 
Ich weiss nicht, ob die o.g. Information in diesem Fall relevant ist.

Andere Beispiele der Flexion zweier Adjektive, die mich interessieren:

**Beispiel Nr. 2:**
Was ist korrekt (es geht hier vor allem um die Endung des Wortes *andere(n)*):

> Welche andere Fragen haben Sie?

oder:

> Welche anderen Fragen haben Sie?

Wird in diesem Fall die gleiche Regel wie beim ersten Beispiel angewendet?

**Beispiel Nr. 3:**

> Die vielen anderen Fragen stehen noch offen.

Dieser Satz ist ähnlich zum ersten Beispiel, aber es gibt einen bestimmten Artikel in diesem Satz. Ist der o.g. Beispielsatz korrekt?

Comment: Servus und willkommen beim Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [tour] der Seite nehmen. Fragen beantwortet dir das [help]. Allerdings vermute ich, dass deine Frage geschlossen werden könnte, denn sie kann recht gut mit einem Grammatikbuch beantwortet werden. Hast du schon eines befragt, und wenn ja, warum hat dir dessen Antwort nicht geholfen?

Comment: Der Frage mangelt es an Kontext, das ist immer schlecht. Je nachdem kann beides richtig sein: _Gehen inzwischen viele anderen Fragen nach?_ und _Hat er noch viele andere Fragen?_

Comment: @chirlu: Gute Bemerkung. Ich habe nicht gewusst, dass es solche Kombinationen geben kann. Ich werde meine Frage ergänzen.

Comment: @Jan: Ich habe nicht gewusst, dass man auf dieser Webseite keine Fragen stellen darf, die man mittels einem Grammatikbuch beantworten kann. Ich habe sogar keine solche Information in der von Dir empfohlenen [tour](http://german.stackexchange.com/tour) gefunden. Es steht dort: "we’re working together to build a library of detailed answers to **every** question about the German language." Ausserdem, die Flexion zweier Adjektive scheint doch einige Ausnahmen zu haben: [Flexion zweier Adjektive in der Nominalgruppe](http://goo.gl/nL1cHJ).

Comment: Bitte **nicht** neuen Nutzern sofort einen -1 geben. Eine Frage –vor allem die erste– zeigt ganz wenig über einen Nutzer.

Comment: Vote für reopen: Ich würde noch als zweiten Beispielsatz "Die vielen anderen Fragen verwirren sie." dazunehmen und daran versuchen die Bedeutung von Kasus, Plural und bestimmten Artikel für die Deklination von Adjektiven zu erklären. Das ist nicht so trivial, wie man auf den ersten Blick denkt ^^

Comment: @krm Da hast du nicht Unrecht. In der Hauptsache geht es dabei darum, dass wir die relativ einfachen Fragen (»Heißt es ›roter Apfel‹ oder ›rote Apfel‹?«) verhindern wollen, die man recht einfach in einem Grammatikbuch nachschlagen kann. Ähnliches macht meines Wissens auch SO, indem sie einen »show your research«-Grundsatz aufstellen. Wir haben uns qua Meta-Beschluss entschieden, dass einfache Grammatik- oder Übersetzungsfragen in der Frage bereits zeigen sollen, dass entsprechende Nachschlagewerke nicht geholfen haben.

Comment: @c.p. Es werden nicht Nutzer bewertet, sondern Fragen. Da nach 3 Wochen niemand mehr weiß, dass das des Users erste Frage war, ist es Quatsch diese unterschiedlich zu behandeln als spätere. Wenn Negativbewertungen den Zweck haben, den Frager zu erziehen, dann sind gerade die ersten Bewertungen die wichtigsten. Schlechte Angewohnheiten lassen sich schlecht austreiben. Auch sind schlechte Fragen natürlich ein schlechtes Vorbild - egal wie lange der User dabei ist. Vote down! Vote early down! Vote often down! ;)

Comment: @c.p. Ist nach dem edit auch definitiv nicht mehr nötig oder zu rechtfertigen ;-)

Comment: @userunknown  *Vote Down!*, ja. *Vote often down!*. Das stimme ich dir auch zu. Aber *Vote early down* (besonders ohne jegliche Erklärung) ist mit Vorsicht zu genießen , denn es wirkt nicht besonders positiv auf den Menschen hinter dem Computer aus. Man kann wohl auch die erste Frage negativ bewerten, doch *diese* war nicht besonders schlecht (ich spreche über die 1. Version). Nun, das sage ich als Befürworter des toleranten *-1*, der ca. 300 *-1* s verteilt hat.

Comment: @c.p.: User krm hat 7 silberne Orden auf SO gesammelt, wo er mit > 600 Punkten seit über 2 Jahren Mitglied ist - er sollte also mit den Konventionen vertraut sein und keinen Welpenschutz benötigen. Ob Du die Frage besonders schlecht fandest kann als Kriterium schlecht verwendet werden, außer Du gibst uns allen Deine Rufnummer, damit wir Dich immer vorher fragen können. Man muss sich beim Bewerten schon auf die eigenen Maßstäbe verlassen.

Comment: @peterh Even if the content of two questions were the same, but one was asked and answered in English, the other in German, then the current consensus is to [leave the question open](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-with-duplicate-questions-in-another-language).

Comment: @Philipp Thanksgiving, good to know! I agree this rule.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wichtig für die Deklination von Adjektiven ist der Fall des Substantivs, ob das Substantiv singular oder plural ist, das Genus des Artikels und ob es einen bestimmten Artikel oder unbestimmten Artikel hat:

---

> Es stehen noch **viele andere** Fragen offen.

- „(Wer oder) Was steht offen?“ Fall: Nominativ
- „viele Fragen“ = Plural + unbestimmter Artikel, der im Plural entfällt
- „eine Frage“ ist feminin

→ Siehe [hier 2. Beispiel (mit unbestimmtem Artikel)](http://www.udoklinger.de/Deutsch/Grammatik/Adjektiv.htm)

> „Die **vielen anderen** Fragen stehen noch offen.“ 
>   „Die **vielen anderen** Fragen verwirren sie.“

- „(Wer oder) Was steht offen?“/„(Wer oder) Was verwirrt sie?“ Fall: Nominativ,
- „die vielen Fragen“ = Plural + bestimmter Artikel
- „die Frage“ ist feminin

→ Siehe [hier 1. Beispiel (mit bestimmtem Artikel) Plural](http://www.udoklinger.de/Deutsch/Grammatik/Adjektiv.htm)

Es gilt in beiden Fällen: Zwei oder mehrere Adjektive vor einem Nomen werden parallel, d. h. auf die gleiche Weise, dekliniert.

---

> „Welche **anderen** Fragen haben Sie?“

- „(Wen oder) Was haben Sie?“ Fall: Akkusativ
- Das „welche“ lese ich hier als nähere Bestimmung von „Fragen“, d. h., es ist äquivalent zu „die vielen Fragen“ = Plural + bestimmter Artikel
- „die Frage“ ist feminin

→ Siehe [hier 1. Beispiel (mit bestimmtem Artikel) Plural](http://www.udoklinger.de/Deutsch/Grammatik/Adjektiv.htm)

> „Ich habe eine **andere** Frage.“

- „(Wen oder) Was habe ich?“ Fall: Akkusativ
- „eine andere Frage“ = Singular + unbestimmter Artikel
- „eine Frage“ ist feminin

→ Siehe [hier 1. Beispiel (mit bestimmtem Artikel) Singular](http://www.udoklinger.de/Deutsch/Grammatik/Adjektiv.htm)

Comment: +1 diese antwort beweist, dass du dich besser für erklärungen eignest als ich. ;)

Comment: Der dritte Fall löst sich als *wen oder was* auf, also Akkusativ. Kann man leicht erkennen, wenn man statt *Frage(n)* zum Beispiel *Baum* (oder ein beliebiges anderes maskulines Substantiv) nimmt: »Welche**n** andere**n** Baum haben Sie?«. Außerdem ist für die Pluralformen das Genus irrelevant: Im Deutschen fallen die grammatikalischen Geschlechter im Plural zusammen und werden nicht mehr unterschieden.

Comment: In dem Zusammenhang fällt auch auf, dass der 4. Fall falsch beschrieben ist: Es ist dort auch ein Akkusativ. (»Ich habe eine**n** andere**n** Baum.«) Ich habe mich nicht getraut, dass auszubessern, weil du anscheinend mit Überzeugung »Nominativ« geschrieben hast. Besser es aus, und dir ist mein +1 sicher.

Comment: @Jan, du meist, "„Was habe ich?“ Fall: Nominativ". Ändere es ruhig, falls du denkst, es sei falsch. Ich vertraue dir da. Fälle waren noch nie meins...

Comment: Schon geschehen ^^ Wie gesagt, der Baum (oder der Hund, oder Kater oder Depp … was auch immer du gerne hernimmst) wirkt da wunder, denn maskuline Nomen sind in jedem Kasus anders: Ein anderer Baum steht. Eines anderen Baumes Blatt fällt. Ich spreche mit einem anderen Baum. Ich sehe einen anderen Baum.

Comment: @Jan, danke! :) (must be at least 15 characters)

Comment: @Iris, Jan: danke. Es hat mich überrascht im Fall von "Welche anderen Fragen haben Sie?", dass "welche" auf gleiche Weise wie ein bestimmter Artikel behandelt wird. Ist es im Fall vom Wort "keine" auch so, dass es wie ein bestimmter Artikel in solchem Fall behandelt wird?

Comment: @kmr, ja, ich denke, denn ein Beispielsatz wäre zum Beispiel: **Es wurden keine anderen guten Fragen gestellt.** Ich bin mir da aber nicht mehr sicher und ich habe leider kein Grammatikbuch zu Hand.

Answer (score 6):

Korrekt ist:

> viele andere Fragen

Zweite Option:

> die viele**n** andere**n** Fragen

Comment: Vielen Dank für die schnelle Antwort. Ich werde noch eine Weile warten, bis ich diese Antwort als die richtige Antwort markiere, um auch anderen Leuten eine Chance zu geben.

Comment: @krm klar kein Problem. Andere haben vielleicht auch die Zeit und das Verständnis, auführlichere Antworten zu liefern. Ich hoffe dennoch ich konnte dir mit dieser kurzen Antwort helfen.

Comment: Gut wäre auch eine Erklärung warum es korrekt ist. Dann wäre es auch +1 wert.

Comment: @Iris: Du kannst auch eine Erklärung schreiben und ich werde Dir +1 geben. Ich habe bemerkt, dass hier bisher nur die Leute +1 bekommen haben, die andere Leute kritisiert haben. Ich war anscheinend die einzige Person, die WayneEra +1 für seine Antwort gegeben hat, weil er mir geholfen hat. Meine Frage ist dafür sogar downvoted worden. Meine Erfahrung aus anderen StackExchange-Seiten ist so, dass diejenigen +1 bekommen, die helfen.

Comment: @ kmr, bevor du deine Frage editiert hast, war diese Antwort zwar auf den ersten Blick richtig, aber ziemlich nutzlos, denn wie Chirlu geschrieben hat, hätte je nach Kontext beides richtig sein können. Daher meine Kritik an der Antwort von @WayneEra und mein Wunsch nach einer Erklärung.

Comment: ..und ich kann keine ausführlichere Antwort schreiben, da die Frage "put on hold" ist. Ich denke, die wichtigste grammatikalische Regel lautet [**Zwei oder mehrere Adjektive vor einem Nomen werden  parallel, d.h. auf die gleiche Weise,  dekliniert.**](http://www.udoklinger.de/Deutsch/Grammatik/Adjektiv.htm)

Comment: @Iris Dann bliebe noch die Frage offen, warum "viele andere Fragen" und nicht "vielen anderen Fragen" richtig ist. ;)

Comment: @Em1, ein Beispielsatz für zweiteren Fall wäre: "Sie ist verwirrt von den vielen anderen Fragen." ;) Das ist gar nicht so trivial, wie ich dachte. Ich schreibe eine ausführliche Antwort sobald die Frage wieder offen ist.

Comment: @Iris: Ich habe die Frage erweitert, daher vielleicht sie wird wieder offen sein. Man muss warten.

Answer (score 3):

Natürlich *können* alle vier korrekt sein, aber nur, wenn *viele(n)* und *andere(n)* nicht zum gleichen Substantiv gehören, wie in den folgenden Beispielen:

- > Wenn vielen andere Fragen gestellt werden.
- > Wenn viele anderen Fragen nachgehen.

Gefragt ist aber nach den Fällen, in denen *viele(n)* und *andere(n)* zusammengehören, weil sie dasselbe Substantiv beschreiben.

Dabei gilt der Grundsatz der Kongruenz: Da beide mehr oder weniger als Adjektive behandelt werden können, sollten sie auch grundsätzlich dieselbe Form haben. Das ist tatsächlich so, wie die vier folgenden Beispiele zeigen. (Da es im Plural nur einen Pluralkasus gibt, erspart sich mir, Gott sei Dank, das zusätzliche Behandeln von *Hund* (maskulin) und *Haus* (neutral).)

- Nominativ:

  > Viele Fragen stehen in dem Buch.
  >   Andere Fragen stehen in dem Buch.
  >
  > Viele andere Fragen stehen in dem Buch.
- Genitiv:

  > Das Buch vieler Fragen.
  >   Das Buch anderer Fragen.
  >
  > Das Buch vieler anderer Fragen.
- Dativ:

  > Das Buch mit vielen Fragen.
  >   Das Buch mit anderen Fragen.
  >
  > Das Buch mit vielen anderen Fragen.
- Akkusativ:

  > Das Buch stellt viele Fragen.
  >   Das Buch stellt andere Fragen.
  >
  > Das Buch stellt viele andere Fragen.

Demnach ist *viele andere Fragen* korrekt, wenn sie im Nominativ oder im Akkusativ stehen, während *vielen anderen Fragen* korrekt ist, wenn sie im Dativ stehen (und *vieler anderer Fragen,* wenn des Genitivs Herrschaft gilt).

Es ändert sich, wenn ein bestimmter Artikel dazugenommen wird:

- Nominativ:

  > Die vielen Fragen stehen in dem Buch.
  >   Die anderen Fragen stehen in dem Buch.
  >
  > Die vielen anderen Fragen stehen in dem Buch.
- Genitiv:

  > Das Buch der vielen Fragen.
  >   Das Buch der anderen Fragen.
  >
  > Das Buch der vielen anderen Fragen.
- Dativ:

  > Das Buch mit den vielen Fragen.
  >   Das Buch mit den anderen Fragen.
  >
  > Das Buch mit den vielen anderen Fragen.
- Akkusativ:

  > Das Buch stellt die vielen Fragen.
  >   Das Buch stellt die anderen Fragen.
  >
  > Das Buch stellt die vielen anderen Fragen.

Im Beisein eines bestimmten Artikels [wechselt die Deklination von starker zu schwacher](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/25357/15318), wodurch in **allen vier Fällen** die Variante mit zwei *n* korrekt ist.

Answer (score 0):

Ist das Vorwort indefinit, dann wird es wie die anderen Adjektive dekliniert (viele andere Fragen). Ist das Vorwort definit, dann bekommen die Adjektive die schwache Deklinationsendung -en. (die anderen Fragen, welche anderen Fragen, alle anderen Fragen, meine kleinen Probleme).