# Adjective endings, with Genitiv

Tags: grammar, english-to-german, adjective, genitive, adjective-ending

"The new car of my friend"
or "My friend's new car"

let's take the second one:
" *My friend's new car* "

in German , could we say : 
das neu**en** Auto mein**es** Freund**es**.  ?

I need help to find the correct translation..

Comment: Could you please explain what you found in your grammar and what questions remain?

Comment: @Stephie is the german translation of the sentence  True or False?

Comment: False, at least the first bolded part.

Comment: ok , give me the correct translation to the sentence: "My friend's new car"

Comment: I'll give you this: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-for-translations-or-about-differences and urge you to take the [tour] and visit our [help].

Comment: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25357/same-noun-same-case-same-adjective-different-ending-what-are-the-rules-behi?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"new" modifies "car", so "neu" needs to be the same case as "Auto":
**das neue Auto**

"My Friend's" is the only Genitiv here and translates to **"meines Freundes" / "meiner Freundin"**.

So "my friend's new car" translates to **"das neue Auto meines Freundes / meiner Freundin"**

Comment: another question ,  the sentence " the new car" is in German " das neue auto" .. why not "das neu auto" , bacause "Auto" is neutral not feminin.. I know that there a grammar to use the adjective, can you please remind me why have you written "neue" and not "neu" .. and thank you so much.:

Comment: Susanne, note why we generally discourage translation requests - it snowballs quickly. It seems OP never checked a grammar book or similar, just expects us to do the work. You'll find more about that on Meta or just ask over on chat. Nevertheless, welcome to German SE - did you take the [tour] and visit our [help] for more information about this specific SE site.

Comment: You might want to start [here](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/343/when-is-a-translation-request-to-german-off-topic), for example.