# What are the difference between "schnellstes" or "am schnellsten"?

Tags: english-to-german, adjective-ending

When we are talking about *fast*, *faster*, and *the fastest*. I don't have any idea how come there are such variations.

> schnell | schneller | am schnellsten
>   schneller | schnelle | schnelles
>   schnellster | schnellste | schnellstes

Comment: Compare [this](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/25357) for the second triplet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*schneller, schnelle, schnelles*

This is just the base form (i.e. "fast"), for all three genders. (*schneller* can also be the comparative for the adjective *schnell*)

Ein **schneller** Hund, eine **schnelle** Taube, ein **schnelles** Kind. (A fast dog, a fast dove, a fast child.)

For the comparative, add -er after schnell-, like so:

Ein schnell**er**er Hund, eine schnell**er**e Taube, ein schnell**er**es Kind. (A faster dog, a faster dove, a faster child.)

For the superlative, add -st after schnell-, keeping the suffix, like so:

Ein schnell**st**er Hund, eine schnell**st**e Taube, ein schnell**st**es Kind. (A fastest dog, a fastest dove, a fastest child.)

It's a bit different (actually easier) if you use the definite article (der, die, das):

Der schnelle Hund, die schnelle Taube, das schnelle Kind (the fast dog, the fast dove, the fast child)

Der schnell**er**e, Hund, die schnell**er**e Taube, das schnell**er**e Kind (the faster dog, the faster dove, the faster child)

Der schnell**st**e, Hund, die schnell**st**e Taube, das schnell**st**e Kind (the fastest dog, the fastest dove, the fastest child)

That said, comparison of adjectives and adverbs can be tricky and you should read up on it in your grammar or variable reputable online sites like this one: http://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/Comparatives/Comparatives.html

Comment: Danke , sehr gut Erklärung

Comment: +1 because you got the u-turn explaining the superlative - there is no "ein schnellster Hund", only "der schnellste Hund". It is possible to say "einer der schnellsten Hunde", then it is a subset of a pack. If there are multiple dogs equally fast or if you are referring to (again) a subset of many dogs it can be "die schnellsten Hunde". e.g. the fastest participants in a dog race could be "die drei schnellsten Hunde". Of those three one still would be "der schnellste"

Comment: @user22338 but that is precisely what he omitted!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Ingmar's very good answer, let me answer your question about "am schnellsten". It is used as a superlative adverb in sentences like

"Maria läuft immer schnell - aber noch schneller, wenn sie verspätet ist. Am schnellsten war sie vor einem Monat, als sie den großen Wettbewerb gewonnen hat".

(Maria is always fast, and even faster when she is late. She was fastest one month ago, when she won the grand race.)

Answer (score 0):

Die Tabellenform ist missverständlich.

Die erste Zeile nennt die Steigerungsformen. Grundform schnell, gesteigert: schneller, Superlativ: am schnellsten.

Die Zeilen 2 und 3 zeigen die Steigerungsformen nach Geschlecht (er, sie, es). Für die Grundform sind fehlt eine solche Zeile, weil die Formen alle gleich sind (Der/Die/Das schnelle X.)

> Ein schneller Löwe, eine schnelle Katze, ein schnelles Huhn.
>
> Schnellste(r/s) Katze/Löwe/Huhn über 50m war Y.