# Strong/Weak declension of adjectives with "alle" and "viele"

Tags: adjective, declension, grammaticality

When do we use the "starke Deklination" and the "schwache Deklination" after "alle" and "viele"?

For example 1:

> Besonders während des berühmten Oktoberfests sind auch alle teure/teuren(?)
>   Hotels ausgebucht.

Example 2:

> Viele geldgierige/geldgierigen(?) Vermieter nutzen die Situation.

Comment: [viel](http://canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Schwankend.html#Anchor-viel-37516) and [alle](http://canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Schwach.html).

Comment: Also [related](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/25357)

Answer (score 1):

first of all it's better to say "Oktoberfest**es**" instead of "Oktoberfest**s**" but both versions are okay.
 Your second question: It's

> "alle teur**en** Hotels"

and

> "viele geldgierig**e** Vermieter"

Why?

 I f you put a "**Begleiter**", like "**der, die, das, alle, sämtliche, beide, derselbe, dieser, jeder, jener, mancher, welcher,...**" then you gonna use the "**schwache Deklination**"

Comment: Isn't it just about if one is referring to the subject or the object of the sentence?

Comment: Don't know exactly what you mean. Look at this [page](http://www.cafe-lingua.de/deutsche-grammatik/schwache-deklination-adjektive.php)

Comment: What leads you to suggest *Oktoberfestes* be better?