# The strong, weak and mixed declension of nouns in German

Tags: noun, declension

Can anyone help with the rules on the strong, weak, and mixed declension of nouns in German? I am particularly interested in those not mentioned in most textbooks.

Also, most people say that there are 4 classes of declension for nouns. Which are these 4 classes?

I have read the rules below, but I am not sure if they are correct, especially with respect to the feminine words:

> A. Masculine / Neuter
>
> 1. Strong declension: The genitive singular ends with *(-e)s*, the nominative plural ends with *-e/-er/-s*.
> 2. Mixed declension: The genitive singular ends with *(-e)s*, the nominative plural ends with *(-e)n*.
> 3. Weak declension: Except for the nominative singular, all other cases end with *(-e)n*.
>
> B. Feminine
>
> 1. Strong declension: The genitive singular without special ending, the nominative plural ends with *-e/-s*.
> 2. Weak declension: The genitive singular without special ending, the nominative plural ends with *(-e)n*.

Comment: Nouns start with capital letter only on German, on English they don't.

Comment: Strong and weak declensions are terms for the inflection of *adjectives*, not nouns. The nouns themselves inflect according to their own class, and there are a lot more than 4 of those. You're better off just learning vocabulary items together with their plural ("Rad/Räder") before worrying about general rules.

Comment: You might find an answer here https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25357/same-noun-same-case-same-adjective-different-ending-what-are-the-rules-behi

Comment: I'm not allowd to comment yet but this is only a comment:
Perhaps what you heard was 4 cases (N,G,D,A) and not 4 classes?

Answer (score 2):

German Grammar has 4 **cases**, not 4 **declension classes** - These are much more.

A case is nominative, accusative, genitive, dative, a declension class is *how those four cases are formed*.

Declension classes are generally distinguished into **strong** and **weak** (and **mixed**, some even state a class of **none**) declension, and further subdivided in many more subclasses.

A full explanation on declension beyond this point is probably too exhaustive for this format. Also note that declension of substantives, adjectives and pronouns can further vary, which makes a full answer even more difficult.

Declension classes are normally used to, well *classify* words into exemplary groups based on empirical systematization of vocabulary - they would normally not help you much with actually **learning** the language