# Grammatical case with "drücken in"

Tags: grammatical-case, adjective, adjective-ending

From the German song "Mein Herz brennt",

The lyrics everywhere online have this

> Sie kommen zu euch in der Nacht
>   Und stehlen eure kleinen heißen Tränen
>   Sie warten bis der Mond erwacht
>   **Und drücken sie in meine kalten Venen** <sup>[Rammstein: Mein Herz brennt](https://g.co/kgs/Yp7b2e)</sup>

Here I think "meine kalten Venen" should be in the accusative case, and hence the adjective "kalten" should be changed to "kalte", am I right?

Comment: I changed the title to reflect one of the topics of your question - please feel free to choose any other wording that suits your concern but please ask more than just *Is this correct?* - thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same noun, same case, same adjective, different ending – what are the rules behind this?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25357/same-noun-same-case-same-adjective-different-ending-what-are-the-rules-behi)

Comment: "kalten Venen" **is** accusative case

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are facing the problem of differentiating between *strong*, *weak*, and *mixed* declension of adjectives. I will illustrate the three forms with the adjective *kalt* and the plural noun *Venen* in accusative case.

#### *Strong* declension

The form *kalte*, which you think was correct, is called *strong* declension. It appears when there is no article or other word declined like an adjective:

> *kalte* Venen

In your example, however, the strong declension does not work, because the pronoun *meine* is also declined like an adjective.

#### *Weak* declension

The *weak* declension appears in connection with a definite article:

> die *kalten* Venen

#### *Mixed* declension

Finally, when there is yet another adjective, or a word that is declined like an adjective (such as *meine*), then *mixed* declension is used:

> *meine* *kalten* Venen

This is actually the form in your example.

Comment: Thanks for bringing these types of declensions to light. That was what was needed!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the full paradigm with "meine kalten Venen" (a somewhat strange topic for a song, though), both with mixed and strong declension endings (for explanation of this difference see other answers on this page):

> Wer? - Meine kalten Venen sind gut sichtbar. - Kalte Venen sind gut sichtbar.
>
> Wessen? - Meiner kalten Venen Blut steht still. - Kalter Venen Blut steht still.
>
> Wem? - Meinen kalten Venen täte jetzt ein Schnaps gut. - Kalten Venen täte jetzt ein Schnaps gut.
>
> Wen? - Meine kalten Venen rubbele ich so lange, bis sie wieder warm werden. - Kalte Venen rubbele ich so lange, bis sie wieder warm werden.

The same thing in singular:

> Wer? - Meine kalte Vene ist gut sichtbar. - Kalte Vene ist gut sichtbar.
>
> Wessen? - Meiner kalten Vene Blut steht still. - Kalter Vene Blut steht still.
>
> Wem? - Meiner kalten Vene täte jetzt ein Schnaps gut. - Kalter Vene täte jetzt ein Schnaps gut.
>
> Wen? - Meine kalte Vene rubbele ich so lange, bis sie wieder warm wird. - Kalte Vene rubbele ich so lange, bis sie wieder warm wird.

(I am glad that I do not have to learn German... what an annoying language!)

I struggle, however, a bit with finding a realistic context for "und drücken sie in meine kalten Venen". Perhaps

> Komm, wir kaufen zwei-drei Spritzen Heroin **und drücken sie in meine kalten Venen**.

This would be socially reprimandable and health-wise unwise, but grammatically it is completely okay.

Or is this about something happening inside (location! Dative!) the veines, as opposed to towards (direction! Accusative!) the veines? A dative construct would require a slightly more complex sentence:

> Ich habe mir in Brasilien Drachenwürmer eingefangen. Nicht nur zwicken **und drücken sie in meine*n* kalten Venen**, man sieht sie auch noch durch, und das findet meine Freundin unschön.

Comment: um das Satzfragment herum könnte man einen ganzen Roman basteln.

Comment: Ja, vielleicht einen Krimi oder Spionageroman, bei dem *und drücken sie in meine kalten Venen* der Schlüsselsatz ist, mit dessen Kenntnis das ganze Rätselgebäude dann kartenhausmäßig in sich zusammenfällt.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is correct, but's in fact a bit tricky.

Because the possessive "meine" acts as a kind of article and, having an ending, carries information about case and number, the following adjective is weak.

Let's look at the simple cases:

> In kalte Venen

Strong adjective because there is no article.

> In die kalten Venen

Weak adjective because of the definite article.

> In meine kalten Venen

Also weak because, as I wrote above, the possessive has an ending with information about case and number.

On the other hand, it's:

> Mein rotes Auto

Because "Mein" does not have an ending and does not carry information about case and number, the following adjective has to be strong.

Comment: Wieso glaubst du, dass "Mein" keine Information über die Anzahl enthält? Die Endung "" verweist für mich ganz klar auf Singular und Nominativ.

Comment: Das bezieht sich darauf, dass "Mein" hat keine Endung hat. Wäre es ein Adjektiv, müsste die Endung -es lauten. Dass sich erschließen lässt, dass es sich um Nominativ oder Akkusativ Singular handeln muss, weil im Neutrum nur diese keine Endung haben, habe ich hier mal außer acht gelassen.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* accusative case (mixed inflection because of "meine"), but it's plural. "Kalte" would be singular, but "Venen" is plural, so only "kalten" fits.