# Adjective Endings - Alternative Learning Method?

Tags: adjective-ending

While trying to finally nail the adjective endings I stumbled upon this article suggesting a simplified way of learning it:

https://www.learn-german-smarter.com/learn-german-adjective-endings/

But either I do not understand their 2nd principle or the entire idea falls apart while dealing with an example like this:

> Ich bin im rheinhessischen Dorf Wiesoppenheim aufgewachsen.

Okay, that's a dual preposition and dative. If I understand the article correctly dative results in an `im (in dem)` but then where does the `en` ending in `rheinhessischen` come from?

Can someone please clarify?

**Edit:** Also I don't see how this unified table in the article will work with plurals. For instance for this example (plural and nominative):

> Die anderen Kinder sind bösartig.

It would suggest `e` ending while the correct one is `en`. Does it also fall back to the 2nd principle where `Die` takes a case ending `e`? Where does the `en` came from again?

Comment: Are you looking at the right table? The unified table is hidden behind a link that says *Click here to download the table for FREE*, which I can't actually click but which points [here](https://www.learn-german-smarter.com/download/720/).

Comment: Indeed I has been looking at [this](https://www.learn-german-smarter.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/German-Adjectives-Case-Endings.jpg) table. Ah, would if it were so simple.

Comment: [This question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25357/same-noun-same-case-same-adjective-different-ending-what-are-the-rules-behi) deals with adjective endings. I have just added what I believe to be the simplest exposition of the rules governing adjective endings.

Comment: Thanks. It's a nightmare. I'm seriously thinking about not using adjectives at all. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ich bin im rheinhessischen Dorf Wiesoppenheim aufgewachsen.

You already found out: *im = in + dem.* And I think you also know, that *dem* is a definite article, and the whole nominal group is in dative case. And the noun *Dorf* is neuter (*das Dorf*). So you have to look for:

- definite article
- neuter
- dative case

So you need to consult table 1, line 3 column 2, and there you find: **∙en.** So the attributive Adjective must be:

> rheinhessisch**en**

---

> Die anderen Kinder sind bösartig.

Here we have:

- definite article
- plural
- nominative case

This means: Table 1 (definite article), line 1 (nominative), Column 4 (plural), and there again you find: **∙en.** So the attributive Adjective must be:

> ander**en**

So, nothing wrong with those tables.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping [this table](https://www.learn-german-smarter.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/German-Adjectives-Case-Endings.jpg) is a sort of all-in-one thing.

Comment: @TimBezhashvyly: No, it is not. There are three tables, and they are different.

Answer (score 1):

Those tables are far too complicated. The single table that claims to simplify things is even worse.

If you understand the system behind adjective declension and learn a few simple rules you don't need to learn tables.

Here's how to work out the adjective ending:

1. **Definite article** (der/die/das) and similar (dieser, solcher etc.)

   - plural *-en*
   - dative/genitive *-en*
   - masc-accusative *-en*

     > die netten Kinder, dem alten Mann, des alten Mannes, den alten Mann
   - all the rest *-e*

     > der junge Mann
2. **Indefinite article** (ein/eine) and similar (kein, mein etc.)

   - where the definite article ending gets 'lost' (m/n-nominative, n-accusative) the adjective has to provide the missing definite article ending

     > da**s** rote Haus -> ein rote**s** Haus
     >   de**r** alte Mann -> ein alte**r** Mann
   - all the rest are the same as above
3. **No article**

   - the adjective provides the missing definite article ending

     > frische**s** Brot, warm**e** Brötchen
   - exception: m/n-genitive take *-en*

     > heiß**en** Kaffees

Summary: you want to see a case ending. If the article doesn't provide it, the adjective does

Comment: Thank you for such a precise overview!
"warme Brötchen" is because the noun is in plural: "die Brötchen" not in singular "das Brötchen"?