# Adjectival nouns: when do you decline them with an -en versus an -e?

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending

We're learning about adjectival nouns in our German course, and I've studied the declension table for two general cases:

1. Definite article (der- word) present
2. Indefinite article (ein- word) present

What I'm having trouble with is distinguishing between the following two sentences:

1. [Die Deutschen] sprechen Deutsch.
2. Ich kenne [viele Deutsche].

Since Deutsche is plural, why does it not become Deutschen in the second sentence?

Comment: **Close Voters** please do take notice of the fact that we [**do not close to dupes in another language**](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-with-duplicate-questions-in-another-language)

Comment: It’s definite (die) vs indefinite (viele). It’s the same as for the adjective itself: die deutschen Biere, viele deutsche Biere. I cannot give you rules (hence no answer), your declension tables should be able to help you, or you need even more of them.

Comment: @CarstenS So "viele" counts as an indefinite article? (That's not sarcastic, by the way. I'm still learning :D I was under the impression that it's not an article.)

Comment: @AleksandrH, it’s not an article, whether it would sense to treat it as one for this discussion is something that I do not know and also are not that interested in, that part I would leave to grammarians. I am sure that the answer that you got is more reliable in that sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only articles trigger weak inflection, yet *viele* is an adjective.

> die/alle/unsere/keine/... Deutsch**en** (weak ending *-en*)
>
> viel**e** arbeitslos**e** Deutsch**e** (strong ending *-e*, no article present)
>
> die viel**en** arbeitlos**en** Deutsch**en** (weak ending *-en*)

For further details, refer to my answer to [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25357/same-noun-same-case-same-adjective-different-ending-what-are-the-rules-behi).

Comment: So really, the two categories are "definite article present" and "definite article absent", not "indefinite article present" for the second one, right?

Comment: Very close. As the first example shows, it isn't really about the definite article: all articles that have an ending (*-e* in this case) behave in the same way. In the singular, *Guter Vorschlag!* and *Ein guter Vorschlag!* both show *-er* because for the adjective, it makes no difference whether there is no article (first example) or an article without an ending (*ein* in the second example; could also be *mein, kein*).

Comment: Oh, so the adjectival nouns just follow the three-scenario rules for normal adjectives: 1) weak if definite article present, 2) strong if no article at all, 3) mixed if indefinite article or ein- word (like a possessive)? That seems to be the case, at least. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, no 100% guarantee that my answer is correct, but i think this is a very special case:
The difference is "[Die Deutschen] sprechen Deutsch." means "the Germans are speaking German" while "Ich kenne [viele Deutsche]." means "i know may German people".
While "die Deutschen" is a standard noun, Deutsche is (I don't know the english term for it) an adjektiv turned into a noun. But this is an exception. It only applies to "German"/"Deutsche".
And it happens because ot the 'sch' in "deutsch". this leads to this strange case. e.g. Russians would be "Die Russen" and "viele Russische" or "viele Russen". Hope i could help.

Comment: It’s perfectly normal for a nominalised adjective: die Kleinen, viele Kleine.

Comment: It actually is a standard noun :) See also here: https://wortwuchs.net/standart-standard/

Comment: ah, snap. I'm always doing that mistake. Why can't i learn from them? x.x