# Why "eine Kind" and not "ein Kind"?

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english, standard-german

> Jede Familie hat dieses eine Kind

Why in this sentence, we use *eine* and not *ein*, despite the fact that *Kind* is neutral (*das Kind*)?

Comment: The sentence means "Every family has this kind of child" or "Every family has such a child"

Comment: Please **complete the sentence** or at least show more of it. The current form doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Downvoted because of missing context. The sentence is uncomplete and not understandable as it is, and, I think, can only be transferred into a more or less normal sentence by giving it a very unexpected spin - see @Wolf's interpretation below.

Comment: btw, I found this question after I read in a book "da war dieser eine Tag gewesen, an dem...". This usage of 'eine' surprised me too.

Answer (score 14):

*Eine* is not an article here, but behaves like an adjective (or numeral) meaning "one", since *dieses* already fulfills the article role. Compare:

- *dieses/das/jedes eine Kind* -- this/the/each one child
- *dieses/das/jedes nervige Kind* -- this/the/each annoying child
- *dieses/das/jedes kranke Kind* -- this/the/each sick child

These are some examples of determiners that require the weak adjective declension to follow.  *Ein*, as an article, requires the strong declension, however:

- *ein gute**s** Kind* - a good child

(Side note: *jedes eine Kind* is acceptable, but *jedes einzelne* is a much more idiomatic version corresponding to "each one".)

---

Now to the discussion about whether I may refer to *ein* as an or "like an" adjective.  You can skip this if you just wanted the direct answer to the question.

Thinking about how we define parts of speech, we can first observe that there are certain syntactic constructions in which only certain kinds of words fit.  On the other hand, we name certain constructions after the "natural" classes of words that form them.  That is essentially a chicken-egg-problem, although in most cases, the classes are clear enought for us to make sense in practical usage ("Krankenhaus", "wusste").  But the point I'm trying to make here is that often you can't just assign a definite part of speech to a "word", but only to the usage of it within a construction.

In my opinion, this leads to two ways of looking at parts of speech for non-prototypical cases: either to apply them rather finely grained, but potentially allowing multiple options per type (this questions the definition of how to split "words" into lexemes); or to take them only as a coarse notion, regarding the function within a construction as the "real thing" to be used in precise treatment.  I personally tend to the latter.
If a reader considers this position too relativistic, I ask them to give me a satisfying general definition of "adverb" in German.

In the case of *ein*, finding "one POS to rule them all" is especially difficult, since it has so many grammatical and lexical functions.  But *eine Kind* in the phrase *das eine Kind* is syntactically an adjective phrase, which is why I called the usage adjectival.  For the same reasoning, I would also call *gehend* in *das gehende Kind* "adjectival".  So, isn't *gehend* a participle? Are all participles adjectives? Can it be both?

And now my reference, long awaited.  Helbig & Buscha, *Deutsche Grammatik*, in the edition from 1986 says on pages 323 ff. on the **Zahladjektiv** (section 3.6):

> Von den Kardinalia wird nur die Zahl 1 vollständig flektiert. [...]
>   Bei den Singularformen ist danach zu unterscheiden, ob die Zahl
>   adjektivisch-attributiv oder als substantivisch gebrauchtes Adjektiv
>   steht und ob sie mit Nullartikel oder mit bestimmtem Artikel (bzw.
>   einem entsprechenden Artikelwort) gebraucht wird. Die
>   adjektivisch-attributive Kardinalzahl wird nach Nullartikel wie der
>   unbestimmte Artikel, nach bestimmtem Artikel wie ein adjektiv in
>   gleicher Stellung flektiert. [...] Man vgl.:
>
> - *Ein* Schüler hat gefehlt. (adjektivisch-attributiv nach Nullartikel)
> - Der *eine* Schüler hat gefehlt (adjektivisch-attributiv nach bestimmtem Artikel)

Now this does not say that *ein* is the totally the same as an adjective, and this also never was what I intended to imply.  But it is clearly regarded as behaving like one in such a construction.  (The interpretation of the other *ein* following a zero article is one I could not really defend, though.)

Comment: *Ein* cannot be an **adjective**! It would be an **adverb** in phrases like "ein und aus". But here, *ein* is an **indefinite pronoun** with the antonym *ander*. See, e.g., https://www.dwds.de/wb/ein#d-1-2-2

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ich will mich nicht an der Diskussion aufhängen, aber bleibe bei der Meinung, dass es sich hier _nicht_ wie ein Pronomen verhält. Weder hat es eine semantisch deiktische Funktion oder steht für eine Nominalphrase, noch (wenn man es generativistisch betrachtet) steht es im Specifier einer Nominalphrase. Wenn schon, würde ich es als Zahlwort bezeichnen, das in dierser Konstruktion eine speziellere Bedeutung bildet. (Der "stengen" Einteilung von allem in exakte Wortarten gegenüber bin ich ja sowieso suspekt.)

Comment: Ausserdem ist an _das eine Kind_ nichts indefinit. Im Gegenteil, es geht um ein speziell hervorgehobenes.

Comment: Den Wörterbüchern kann man nicht vertrauen. DWDS sagt unter III. 1. "adjektivisch" und macht dann Beispiele mit dem Artikelwort. Immerhin mit *dieser eine Fehler* ein Beleg als Adjektiv. Dort auch kein Kontrast zu *ander-*, sondern Zahladjektiv.

Answer (score 3):

## Homonymy

The problem at the core of the question is [homonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym): Two words that are spelled the same, yet have different properties. A popular example involving two nouns would be *Mutter*, pl. *Mütter* "mother" and *Mutter*, pl. *Muttern* "nut" (on a screw).

In German, there is **systematic homonymy** between determiners (*Artikelwörter*) and pronouns. For instance, compare the definite article and the demonstrative pronoun.

> Sag mal, kennst du **die** neu**en** Kollegen? *(determiner)*
> Sag mal, die neuen Kollegen, kennst du **die**? *(pronoun)*

In the first example, the definite article *die* triggers weak inflection (*-en*) on the following adjective; the pronoun, seemingly identical in form, cannot co-occur with an adjective.

Note that I say seemingly identical because the two words inflect differently in the dative plural.

> Hast du schon mit **den** neuen Kollegen gesprochen? *(determiner)*
> Die neuen Kollegen, hast du schon mit **denen** gesprochen?  *(pronoun)*

The difference between pronouns and determiners becomes even more apparent for those determiners that are uninflected in the nominative singular masculine and neuter because the pronoun then carries the strong ending.

> Kannst du mir **dein** Wörterbuch leihen?  *(determiner, no ending)*
> Ich habe mein Wörterbuch vergessen, kannst du mir **deins** leihen? *(pronoun, strong ending)*

Let's recap:

- Determiners, when inflected, trigger weak inflection on following adjectives.
- Pronouns stand alone. They can, in some cases, be distinguished from determiners by their endings (*denen* vs. *den* in the dative plural; neuter *eins/keins/meins* versus *ein/mein/kein*).

## The grammar of *ein*: triple homonymy

The following phrase, as noted by phipsgabler,

> dies**es** ein**e** Kind

is exactly parallel to

> dies**es** klein**e**, frech**e**, klug**e** ... Kind

with a demonstrative article carrying the strong ending (*-es*) and triggering weak inflection (*-e*) on the following adjective.

Grammatically, *ein* can be a determiner, an adjective, or a pronoun, i.e. we have a case of **triple homonymy**.

1. As a **determiner** (called the indefinite article) it precedes adjectives. It is uninflected in the nominative singular masculine and neuter; when it is inflected, it triggers weak inflection on the adjective.

> Morgen kommt **ein** neuer Kollege. *(determiner no ending, adjective strong)*
> Ich habe eben **einem** neuen Kollegen den Kopierer erklärt.  *(determiner strong, adjective weak)*
> Das war die Idee **eines** neuen Kollegen. *(determiner strong, adjective weak)*

As a determiner, it behaves just like the possessive determiners *mein, dein, unser …* and the negative determiner *kein*.

2. As an **adjective**, it follows a determiner and inflects like an adjective, i.e. it is weak if the determiner is inflected.

> Das ein**e** Bier trinke ich noch. *(weak)*
> Mit dem ein**en** Kollegen gibt es immer Probleme. *(weak)*
> Mein **einer** Wunsch ist, dass wir alle gut durch diese Krise kommen. *(strong)*

As an adjective, it can be replaced by another adjective.

> Das offen**e** Bier trinke ich noch.
> Mit dem neu**en** Kollegen gibt es immer Probleme.

3. As a **pronoun**, it stands on its own and inflects strongly.

> Wo ist denn mein Regenschirm? – Da liegt **einer**.
> Du hast doch in diesem Jahr bestimmt noch kein Buch gelesen. – Doch, **eins**!

As a pronoun, it can be replaced by the possessive pronouns and the negative pronoun.

> Wo ist denn mein Regenschirm? – Hier ist **keiner**.
> Du hast doch in diesem Jahr bestimmt schon viele Bücher gelesen. – Nein, **keins**.

## Meaning: indefiniteness vs. cardinal number

The most common use of *ein* is an indefinite article, i.e. introducing something that is new to the listener.

> Vorsicht, da kommt **ein** Auto.

The indefinite meaning is inherently incompatible with those instances where *ein* as an adjective is preceded by a definite or demonstrative article; in those cases, it is used as a cardinal number.

> Das **eine** Bier trinke ich noch.

The indefinite article is ambiguous between both readings. The correct one has to be inferred from the context when reading; in spoken language, *ein* will be stressed when it refers to the number. In the following example, stressed *EIN* is interpreted as a cardinal number and would be translated by English *one*.

> **EIN** Anruf und alles war geklärt.

## Further reading

For more background on adjectives, determiners and strong and weak inflection see my answer to the question [Same noun, same case, same adjective, different ending – what are the rules behind this?](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/48626/35111).

The *Institut für Deutsche Sprache* has excellent grammatical resources online. However, they are not suited for beginners. On adjectives, see for instance the section [Flexion der Adjektive](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/progr@mm/4067) of the *Propädeutische Grammatik*. On number adjectives, they say:

> Die Flexion der deutschen Zahladjektive ist teilweise uneinheitlich. Ordinalzahl-Adjektive (z. B. *der **dritte** Mann, das **fünfte** Gebot*) werden regelmäßig stark oder schwach flektiert. Auch das Kardinalzahl-Adjektiv *ein* (nicht zu verwechseln mit dem indefiniten Artikel oder Indefinit-Pronomen *ein-*) wird normalerweise stark oder schwach flektiert.
>
> > *Ich habe nur das **eine** Fahrrad. Mit dem **einen** Fahrrad können wir nicht zu zweit fahren.*

The relevant DWDS entry is [III. 1](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ein#d-1-3-1), which talks about a cardinal number used as an adjective and has the example *dieser eine Fehler durfte nicht passieren*.

The relevant Duden entry is [ein (Zahlwort)](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ein_Zahl) with the example *die Ereignisse dieses einen Jahres*.

The Duden Grammar covers the topic under paragraph [451 f](https://books.google.de/books?id=ry6tCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=duden%20grammatik&pg=PA337#v=snippet&q=451&f=false). They call *ein-* in the relevant context *unbestimmtes Zahladjektiv* and the examples include:

> Er kaufte den Smoking für dieses **eine** Fest.
> Doch dieses **eine** Auge sah alles.

Comment: Ich gebe es langsam auf. Ich dachte, die obige Diskussion hätte klar gemacht, dass *ein* kein Adjektiv ist! Sonst würde man neben „Das *eine* Bier“ auch schreiben können: *„Ein eines und helles Bier.“* oder *„Das Bier ist ein.“* Wenn Sie trotzdem daran festhalten wollen, dann liefern Sie bitte endlich eine Quelle, und dann verspreche ich, bin ich ruhig! Ich selbst habe vier Quellen geliefert, von denen nicht eine besagt, dass *ein* ein Adjektiv wäre. PS: Den Rest der Erklärungen finde ich gut!

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Starke Endung dann mit dem Possessivartikel *mein einer Wunsch*. Eine Quelle in der Antwort. Nicht online: Duden-Grammatik, 8. Aufl., Randnr. 446-52 und 509.

Comment: Ich sag mal so: Die Unterscheidung zwischen Begleitern (determiner) und Pronomen ist schon mal eine Dauerbaustelle der deutschen Grammatik. Das ist hier ganz gut gelöst. Doch auch die Trennlinie zwischen Begleitern und Adjektiven ist alles andere als klar. Es gibt Artikelphrasen (Kombinationen mehrerer Begleiter: in diesem unserem Lande, ein jeder Bürger unserer Stadt, welch ein Schlamassel!, dieses eine Mal) und Artikelvariation (so ein komischer Typ, was für eine Bluse suchen Sie?) und -gradation (ein einziger / sehr viele / kaum ein / fast kein Zuschauer). Für all solche Fälle separate ...

Comment: ... Regeln aufzustellen, verwirrt. Kurz gesagt verhält sich der Komplex aus Artikelwörtern und Adjektiven vor einem Nomen nach einfachen Prinzipien. Im Normalfall steht die Genus+Kasus-Markierung möglichst weit links, wenn nicht (wie bei kein anderer Kollege), geht sie auf das nachfolgende Wort über. Es stimmt, dass _ein_ als Zahl-Begleiter von vielen (allen?) Grammatiken als Adjektiv aufgefasst wird, darüber kann man streiten. Hier ist es Zahlbegleiter und wird dekliniert wie ein Adjektiv. Es hat jedoch auch determinierende Funktion und ist kein 'normales' Adjektiv.

Comment: ... Derartige 'artikelhaftige Adjektive' gibt es in größerer Zahl (ander-, unzählig-, bestimmt-, _ganz_ in 'der ganze' ...). Im angefragten Beispiel überwiegt der Zahlwort-Charakter bei 'eine'. Das Beispiel ist andererseits rückverweisend (dieses eine Kind), der bezogene Kontext fehlt, ein Kontrast zu _alle anderen Kinder / das andere Kind_ ist nur theoretisch denkbar. wegen _jede_ erscheint mir der Satz falsch bzw. sinnverfälschend unvollständig. Solche verstümmelten Beispiele lassen sich nur durch Spekulationen interpretieren.

Answer (score 2):

In Swiss German this word has an additional `t` anf then is "normally" flected:

> Da ds **einte** Ching bim Giu het übernachtet...
>
> *Da das **eine** Kind beim Jungen hat ...*

---

> Für die **einte** Ching isches bereits ds letschte VAKI-Turne gsi.
>
> *Für die **einen** Kinder ist es bereits das letzte VAKI-Turnen gewesen*

---

> Mir sind zwar nur **z'vierte** im Zimmer, aber de **einti** Maa schnarcht
>   sooooo abartig, das glaubsch nöd!
>
> *zu **viert** im Zimmer...aber der **eine** Mann...*

(these are real examples, just the first search results)

It is constructed and used like a ordinal number: ers-te, zwei-te, drit-te, ...zehn-te etc.

So `ein-te` would be not `one`, `a` or `first`, but something like `oneth`. English has `ones`, which is also a bit paradoxical.

---

In real (standard) German this is difficult to distinguish. It looks like a simple article, but here it is used to single out (the ones...the others...).

The declension rules are complex in this field - depends on more than just genus and numerus.

---

> Dieses einte Kind

I wonder *how* wrong that sounds in Germany, since when, and where maybe less.

---

Mani Matter's intro to his Sandwich song tests the limits of this special word, which somehow is the opposite of "other":

```
De ziet der eint sy einti Hand under der einte Hand vom andere füre
u leit sen uf di anderi Hand vom andere, 
u der ander ziet sy einti Hand under der andere Hand vom einte füre
u leit se uf di einti Hand vom andere – eh, vom einte.

 (dr eint - di einti - vom einte)

Dann zieht der eine seine eine Hand unter der einen Hand des anderen hervor 
und legt sie auf die andere Hand des anderen,
und der andere zieht seine eine Hand unter der anderen Hand des einen hervor
und legt sie auf die eine Hand des anderen - eh, des einen.

 (der eine - die eine - des einen)
```

---

Also ein paar Helvetier hatten - und haben - gar kein Problem damit, auch auf Schriftdeutsch:

Dialekt meets Denglish:

> Nov 17, 2017 - Dieses **einte-mal** haben wir uns auf die Location &
>   Infrastruktur, wie auch Koordination & Timing des Events, wie auch die
>   Show auf der Bühne ...

Es geht aber auch in gehobenem Deutsch - vor 250 Jahren:

> Wie glücklich könnte ein Fürst sein Leben machen, wenn er wöchentlich
>   dergleichen Unterredungen anstellte, das **einte** mal von Gelehrten über
>   einen Theil der ... (Hans Caspar Hirzel - 1774)

Das kann doch nicht an der Staatsgenze enden. Wo sind die Bayern und Österreicher etc., wenn man sie mal braucht?

Die Suche im Internet ist schwierig "einte" gibt es nicht und wird von z.B. von google zu "ente" korrigiert, und "eine" ist zu unspezifisch.

Comment: Sehr interessant. Im Bundesdeutschen klingt _das einte Kind_ völlig falsch, hört sich an wie Ausländerdeutsch - ist es ja dann auch ; )...

Comment: Großartige Komparatistik! Eine Nebenfrage noch: aus welcher Gegend genau stammen deine Dialektbeispiele? (Für bayrische Dialekte fühle ich mich leider nicht qualifiziert, die kann ich als Stadtmensch auch nur im zweiten Bildungsweg...)

Comment: M. Matter ist Berndeutsch, aber kein "breites" oder spezielles, im Gegenteil. Er selber war "us em Aargau", was schön zwischen Bern, Basel und Zürich liegt. Das "de (Maa)...nöd" ist Zürichdeutsch. "Giu" kennt man praktisch nur in Bern. "Ching" ist auch Bern, diese Endung, und als Plural.  Ich hatte "einte ching" und dann "einti maa" eingegeben, wegen der Frage und der Beugung (und damit "Ente" verschwindet). 188 Zeichen noch: "...was i däm Sandwich uf dim Tisch / Für Dialäktik drinnen isch" = "was in diesem Sandwich auf deinem Tisch / Für Dialektik drin ist".  Uhuere viu!

Answer (score 1):

> Jede Familie hat dieses *eine* Kind.

Here, *eine* is not a form of the [definite article *ein*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ein#d-1-1) but of the [indefinite pronoun *ein*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ein#d-1-2-2).

Unfortunately, [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ein#Indefinitpronomen) still lists the wrong forms for the different cases. Therefore, I will list the correct ones here, together with the forms of its antonym [*ander*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ander) (N = Nominativ, G = Genitiv, D = Dativ, A = Akkusativ):

**Neuter:**

- N: das eine / andere Kind
- G: des einen / anderen Kindes
- D: dem einen / anderen Kind
- A: das eine / andere Kind

And for completeness for the other genders:

**Male:**

- N: der eine / andere Mann
- G: des einen / anderen Mannes
- D: dem einen / anderen Mann
- A: den einen / anderen Mann

**Female:**

- N: die eine / andere Frau
- G: der einen / anderen Frau
- D: der einen / anderen Frau
- A: die eine / anderen Frau

---

Based on a discussion in the comments below this and @phipsgabler's answer, I want to add four sources that substantiate my claim that *ein* is an indefinite pronoun:

- [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ein#d-1-2-2)
- [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ein#Indefinitpronomen) (which has the wrong forms in the table)
- [Duden Online](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ein_Pronomen) (hidden in the *Grammatik* section)
- DUDEN 9. Das Wörterbuch der sprachlichen Zweifelsfälle. Entry "**einer (Indefinitum), 2.**" Quote: *"Wenn man das Relativpronomen auf das **Indefinitum einer** bezieht […]"*

Notice that none of the sources claims that *ein* was an *adjective*. Unfortunately, the commentators have not yet provided any other sources that would support their view.

Comment: Can you really call _ein_ an indefinite pronoun in this phrase? You can't say _*das irgendeine Kind_ either.

Comment: @phipsgabler, it's about *ein*, not *irgendein*. By the way, *ein* is not an adjective, as you claim in your answer.

Comment: That's why I was asking you, in genuine curiosity -- why is it not? As far as I can see, it behaves exactly like an adjective here, and some pronouns don't work in its place.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Of course *ein-* can be an indefinite pronoun. That does not preclude it from being an adjective as well. What's your opinion on DWDS III. 1., which says *adjectival*?

Comment: @DavidVogt, adjektivisch = *wie* ein Adjektiv ≠ *ist* ein Adjektiv. phipsgabler hat das ja mittlerweile abgeschwächt, indem er schreibt, dass es sich so verhalte. Dennoch bleibt seine Weigerung, es als das anzuerkennen, was es wirklich ist, nämlich ein *Indefinitum* (vgl. die drei Quellen in meiner Antwort).

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ich verstehe das nicht. Naturlich gibt es indefinites *ein*. Als Artikel und als Pronomen. Das bestreitet doch niemand. Aber in *dieser eine Fehler* hat es eine schwache Endung, ganz wie ein Adjektiv. Und die schwache Endung ist, was den  Fragesteller gestört hat; die wäre mit der Einordnung als Adjektiv erklärt. Immer nur zu wiederholen, *ein* sei indefinit **und nichts anderes**, ist doch Quatsch.

Comment: @DavidVogt. Es ist aber nun mal kein Adjektiv, auch wenn die Formen wie eines aussehen. Was ist denn daran so schwer zu verstehen? Es gibt haufenweise Eigenschaften von zwei Dingen, die sich überschneiden. Deswegen sind die Dinge aber nicht das Gleiche. Zum Beispiel schreibt man am Satzanfang in der Regel groß. Dennoch ist das erste Wort eines Satz nicht immer ein Substantiv. Ähnlich ist das hier: Es mag sein, dass die Formen von *ein* wie die eines Adjektivs aussehen; das macht *ein* aber noch lange nicht zu einem Adjektiv. Ich weiß, dass Sie genügend Sachverstand haben, das nachzuvollziehen.

Comment: Es mag kein Adjektiv sein, aber es kann eine Kardinalzahl sein. Beispiele aus dem [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ein_Zahl): "die Ereignisse dieses einen Jahres" und "der eine (einzige) Gott". Der Duden unterscheidet diese Verwendung von jener als [Adverb](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ein_an_Betrieb) oder [Pronomen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ein_Pronomen). Ich denke auch, dass die Interpretation als Zahlwort im vorliegenden Beispiel besser passt. Es geht darum, dass es in jeder Familie genau 1 "solches" (was auch immer das heißen mag) Kind gibt.

Comment: @Hulk, da stimme ich mit Ihnen überein. Zu bemerken ist noch, dass Duden Online (im Gegensatz zu den gedruckten Ausgaben) Pronomen offenbar generell nicht weiter spezifiziert, also zwischen Indefinit-, Relativ-, Demonstrativ-, Interrogativ- etc. unterscheidet (man muss immer erst unter dem Punkt *Grammatik* nachschauen, was es denn nun ist). Schon deshalb ist Duden Online für solche Fragen ungeeignet.

Comment: Ich bin von deiner Argumentation auch nicht überzeugt (Verleiche mal: *Jede unserer Klassen hat diese zwei, drei Störenfriede.*). Und eigentlich ist auch die Frage, wie der Satz in der Frage eigentlich weiter geht, denn so ist er inhaltlich ziemlicher Unfug.

Comment: @Hulk *`Es geht darum, dass es in jeder Familie genau 1 "solches" (was auch immer das heißen mag) Kind gibt.`* - das habe ich auch erst gedacht. Aber vielleicht lautet der Satz ja in Wirklichkeit so: *Jede Familie hat dieses eine Kind am liebsten sofort adoptieren wollen, weil es so eine reizende Ausstrahlung hat, aber nachdem ich auf seine Erbkrankheit hinwies, gingen sofort die Lichter aus, da war nichts mehr zu machen.* ... auch wenn es in dieser Antwort nichts zur Sache tut.

Comment: @Wolf, was für eine Argumentation? Ich habe vier Quellen konsultiert, phipsgabler, der diese unsinnige Diskussion angezettelt hat und behauptete, es sei ein Adjektiv, nicht eine einzige. Und meine vier Quellen sprechen höchstens von adjektivischem Gebrauch, nicht aber davon, dass *ein* ein Adjektiv sei. Ohne phipsgablers Kommentar hätte es diese Diskussion nicht gegeben (und vermutlich auch nicht die Abwertungen, da die Formen ja wohl trotzdem korrekt sind, egal ob man das Ding nun Adjektiv oder Indefinitum nennt).

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich deine Antwort überzeugt mich nicht (ich habe zu ihr noch kein Votum abgegeben), weil ich aus den Quelle keine einleuchtende Begründung ableiten konnte. Ich halte *ein* nicht für ein Indefinitpronomen weil es *Kind* (oder etwas anderes) in dieser Konstruktion nicht vertritt (*pro nomen*). Was auch immer es ist: behandelt man es beugungsmäßig wie ein Adjektiv, führt das meines Erachtens zu einem korrektem (Halb-)Satz.

Comment: Downvoted because a 'Begleiter' within a nominal phrase can never be a 'Stellvertreter' (substitute) of a nominal phrase. They are two different word classes. You have a similar difference talking of a _co-teacher_ (there are two teachers in the classroom) and a _supply  teacher_ (there is only one teacher). Btw, your Wiktionary reference relates to the *pronoun* 'ein', and the forms given there are not 'wrong'.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers,

> dieses *eine* Kind

could also be translated as:

> this *very* child

Comment: This made my find "[Gott]..., seinen einen Sohn sendend, ..." (Bible, 1828, Grätz/AUT). This is rather "only=einzig" in this context. The Swiss German "einte" would be wrong here, because it implies brothers (i.e.: others ;).  I think you would say: "Si ei  Sohn". but this is church talk/special case. `This Very Child", I like that!  Unity and Truth.

Comment: Oh, that's just like the "eingeborene Sohn", who is also not meant to be "native Earthian", but "single child".