# "Wir suchen nach trockener Rinde" Rinde - is it Akkusativ or Dativ?

Tags: adjective, dative, accusative

> "Wir suchen nach trockener Rinde"

*Rinde* - is it Akkusativ or Dativ?

If it is Akkusativ, why trocken**er** , and not trockene?

Maybe, this is wrong sentence (from fairy tales).

Comment: It's _trocken**er**_ because there is _nach_. But unfortunately I can't explain reasonably why in terms of grammatical rules (native speaker).

Comment: Adjective endings are always a source of problems but [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/25357/35111) should cover the general case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Same noun, same case, same adjective, different ending – what are the rules behind this?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25357/same-noun-same-case-same-adjective-different-ending-what-are-the-rules-behi)

Comment: @RalfFriedl no ))

Answer (score 6):

It is Dativ.

"nach" is always followed by a Dativ, and one way to use "suchen" uses the word "nach" to mark the object one hopes to find.

It is also possible to use "suchen" without "nach". In that case, the phrase would be "wir suchen trockene Rinde", where "Rinde" would be an Akkusativ.