# Suffix "-es" at the and of "großes"

Tags: grammatical-case, adjective-ending

> Wir haben kein großes Bad.

I do not understand why there is *-es* at the and of *großes*. The original word is *groß*. I first thought it was genitive, but then I figure out it is not. Can you help me?

Comment: See also https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25357/same-noun-same-case-same-adjective-different-ending-what-are-the-rules-behi

Answer (score 2):

Let's do it step by step. First, we decompose the sentence:

> [Wir]<sub>(subject, nominative)</sub>  [haben]<sub>(verb)</sub>  [kein großes Bad.]<sub>(accusative object)</sub>

Second, we look up the noun [*Bad*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bad) and see that it is neuter.

Third, we consult the declension tables for the adjective *groß*, for example, at [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:gro%C3%9F). There are three possibilities for neuter gender and accusative case:

- strong declension: *großes*
- weak declension: *das große*
- mixed declension: *ein großes*

The indefinite pronoun [*kein*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/kein) is an article word similar to [*ein*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ein#Artikel). Therefore, mixed declension is in place here, where *kein* is weakly declined and *großes* is strongly declined, i. e., *kein großes Bad*.

You can find more about the topic *declension rules* in [this community wiki](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/25357/25241).

Answer (score 1):

*Bad* is in Akkusativ case here. *Bad* is neuter (*das Bad*).

Since you thought *großes* would be Genitiv (due to the *-es* ending), you seem to mix up the declension of nouns and adjectives. You might want to have a look at the [declension of adjectives](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/en/grammar/adjectives/declension)