# Adjective in dative case (gehen ihrem normaleM Alltag nach)

Tags: adjective, dative

> In Kabul gehen viele Menschen ihrem ganz normalem Alltag nach. Ganz ohne Risiko ist das nicht.

This is written next to a picture here: https://www.kinderweltreise.de/kontinente/asien/afghanistan/alltag-kinder/alltag/

I think that *normalem* should have ended with an *n*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Same noun, same case, same adjective, different ending – what are the rules behind this?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25357/same-noun-same-case-same-adjective-different-ending-what-are-the-rules-behi)

Comment: You're right, "ihrem normale_n_ Alltag" would be correct. It's probably just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, this is once again simply a mistake on the webpage.

In combination with *ihrem*, the adjective [*normal*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:normal#normal_(Deklination)_(Deutsch)) must carry the weak-declension ending *-n*. Thus, the phrase should be

> gehen *ihrem* ganz *normalen* Alltag nach