# How to pronounce and write 19. and related?

Tags: numbers

I have been searching to get to know how I can pronounce 19. and 18. and related, such as:

> im 19. Jahrhundert

However I didn't find anything. I'd like a table with 18., 17., for example, and also examples to apply in phrases. Also I didn't find how to use very well in decades such as in:

> die 20er Jahre

I would like for this if possible, a complete table and also examples of it in a sentence.

Comment: "im neunzehnten Jahrhundert" Why can't you look up "nineteenth" in an English-German dictionary? Many online dictionaries (such as [LEO](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/nineteenth)) even provide pronounciation samples.

Comment: For the numbers themselves, see https://learngerman.dw.com/de/ordnungszahlen-2/l-38483735/gr-39125015.

Comment: If the question is indeed about the formation of ordinal numbers, I oppose closing it. Processes of word formation are not something that can be looked up in a dictionary. For instance, in this case, there is a rule about the distribution of the suffixes and some stem variants that need to be mentioned.

Comment: Übrigens ist "ich kann die Antwort irgendwo im Internet finden" kein gültiger Close-Grund

Comment: @tofro: "Can as well be answered by a dictionary, thesaurus, or conjugation table
The only answers we can post to this question reproduce a dictionary entry or similar" H. Schölnasts Beitrag tut genau das.

Answer (score 2):

- **starke Deklination, männlich, Nominativ: 19. = »neunzehnter«**

  > ein 19. Mann = ein neunzehnter Mann

  Pronunciation: [aɪ̯n ˈnɔɪ̯nˌt͡seːntɐ man]
  Translation: a 19<sup>th</sup> man
- **starke Deklination, weiblich, Nominativ: 19. = »neunzehnte«**

  > eine 19. Frau = eine neunzehnte Frau

  Pronunciation: [ˈaɪ̯nə ˈnɔɪ̯nˌt͡seːntɐ fʁaʊ̯]
  Translation: a 19<sup>th</sup> woman
- **starke Deklination, sächlich, Nominativ: 19. = »neunzehntes«**

  > ein 19. Kind = ein neunzehntes Kind

  Pronunciation: [aɪ̯n ˈnɔɪ̯nˌt͡seːntəs kɪnt]
  Translation: a 19<sup>th</sup> child
- **schwache Deklination, sächlich, Nominativ: 19. = »neunzehnte«**

  > das 19. Jahrhundert = das neunzehnte Jahrhundert

  Pronunciation: [das ˈnɔɪ̯nˌt͡seːntə jaːɐ̯ˈhʊndɐt]
  Translation: the 19<sup>th</sup> century
- **schwache Deklination, sächlich, Dativ: 19. = »neunzehnten«**

  > im 19. Jahrhundert = im neunzehnten Jahrhundert

  Pronunciation: [ɪm ˈnɔɪ̯nˌt͡seːntn̩ jaːɐ̯ˈhʊndɐt]
  Translation: in the 19<sup>th</sup> century

You can find all forms of *neunzehnte* here: [Wiktionary: Flexion:neunzehnte](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:neunzehnte)

Comment: Nachdem 3 close votes da sind und die Frage ganz eindeutig in jedem Wörterbuch und Grundgrammatikbuch beantwortet wird, verstehe ich nicht ganz, warum man mit 102k Reputation hier noch eine Antwort verfasst.

Comment: @infinitezero Vielleicht, weil man, entgegen der Meinung der CV, überzeugt ist, dass das eine sinnvolle Frage ist, die eine Antwort verdient? Was übrigens Huberts Reputation damit zu tun hat, erschließt sich mir nicht.

Comment: So wie's jetzt ist, ist es einfach nur übertragener Inhalt von einem online Wörterbuch...

Comment: Vier Punkte: **1.** Ich habe beim Close-Voting dafür gestimmt die Frage offen zu lassen und ich habe ihr +1 gegeben, weil ich sie für eine gute Frage halte. **2.** Solange eine Frage nicht geschlossen ist, ist sie offen und darf von jedem beantwortet werden. **3.** Bitte poste einen Link auf das Online-Wörterbuch, das auch die verlangte Aussprache enthält. **4.** Inwiefern sollte meine Reputation mich daran hindern, Fragen zu beantworten? Ich habe meine Reputation erhalten, ***weil*** ich viele Fragen beantworte. Es nicht auch gar nicht immer notwendig, jemandens Motivation zu verstehen.

Comment: Nun, ich erwarte von jemandem, der solange und soviele Fragen beantwortet, dass er hinreichend mit der Seite vertraut ist. "Can as well be answered by a dictionary, thesaurus, or conjugation table
The only answers we can post to this question reproduce a dictionary entry or similar"

Comment: und wie kann man mit "mit" oder "seit" sprechen?

Comment: @infinitezero: **3.** Bitte poste einen Link auf das Online-Wörterbuch, das auch die verlangte Aussprache enthält.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast klick halt einen der Links in deinem Wörterbuch an. Gibt sogar Audiodateien dazu: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/neunzehnte alles bequem erreichbar von dem Link, den du in deiner Antwort gepostet hast.

Comment: @infinitezero: Und wenn ich dir sage, dass ich ganz einfach gerne anderen Leuten helfe: Wäre das eine Motivation, die du verstehen könntest? Ich finde es ganz einfach unhöflich und unangebracht, Menschen, die etwas wissen wollen, die Tür vor der Nase zuzuschlagen. Vor allem, weil diese Seite hier ja explizit dazu da ist, Fragen zu beantworten. Davon lebt Stackexchange.

Comment: Klar kann ich das verstehen, geht nur an meinem zitierten Punkt völlig vorbei.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers followed by a dot are known as [ordinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_numeral). For deriving ordinal numbers from cardinal numbers, German uses the suffixes *‑t* and *‑st*. The former is used for numbers below 20.

> Wir waren zu zwei**t**, vier**t**, fünf**t**, …

Some numbers use a different stem for forming the ordinal.

> - eins → erst
> - drei → dritt
> - sieben → siebt

Above 20, *‑st* is used.

> Wir waren zu zwanzig**st**.

The suffix *-t* is also used for variables:

> im n-**t**en Versuch

As the last example shows, ordinal numbers inflect like normal adjectives. In the dative, the weak ending (i.e. the ending used after a determiner such as *im*) is *‑en*.

For an external overview of adjective endings, see https://resources.german.lsa.umich.edu/grammatik/adjektivendungen/. On this site, there is [Same noun, same case, same adjective, different ending – what are the rules behind this?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25357/same-noun-same-case-same-adjective-different-ending-what-are-the-rules-behi).

Answer (score 0):

In German the Numbers in the tens are usually pronounced as the second number first:

19 -> neunzehn -> nineteen        18 -> achtzehn -> eighteen

different from English however we continue this way even at 20 and up

21 -> einundzwanzig (one-and-twenty) -> twentyone

Also, same as in English 11 and 12 have their own names
11 -> elf -> eleven     12 -> zwölf -> twelve

Also for the full 10s:
10 Zehn
20 Zwanzig
30 Dreißig (ß instead of z on this one )
40 Vierzig
50 Fünfzig
60 Sechzig
70 Siebzig
80 Achtzig
90 Neunzig
always number + "zig" with the exception of 30

Examples:

> Diese Firma existiert seit dem zwanzigsten Jahrhundert.
>
> This company existet since the 20th century.

> Ich bin in den Neunzigern geboren.
>
> Ich bin in den Neunzigerjahren geboren. (same meaning)
>
> I was born in the 90s.

Comment: Hello and welcome to GermanSE. Unfortunately, your answer doesn't really address the question. The question was about ordinal numbers, not cardinal numbers.