# Difference between "viele gute Ideen" and "die vielen guten Ideen"

Tags: grammatical-number, declension

Both are plural, but "viele gute Ideen" is missing the plural ending -n (viele guten Ideen). Is there a grammatical explanation for this? Thanks!

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/25357/35111

Comment: I'm pretty sure that these two links should answer the question. Specifically *vielen guten* is the weak declension and *viele gute* is the strong declension.