# Deutsche oder Deutscher

Tags: adjective-ending, nominalization, declension-table

A text I am using has the sentence,

> Sigmund Jähn war der erste Deutsche im All.

Two things seem to be wrong with this sentence. First Sigmund is male, so why not use Deutscher instead of Deutsche? Second Pons tells me that Deutsche is feminine and Deutscher is masculine, so why is it **der erste Deutsche** and not **die erste Deutsche**?

Comment: Erklären kann ich's nicht, aber hundert Beispiele bringen: Der Schnelle, der Langsame, der Schöne, der Hässliche, der Kluge, der Dumme, der Erste, der Letzte, ... alles grammatisch maskulin. "Sieglinde war die erste Deutsche im All" dagegen würde bedeuten, dass Sieglinde die erste dt. Frau im All war, aber nicht die erste dt. Person überhaupt.Aber "Der Sieger beim Wildacher Vierwälderlauf war Ines Bulthaupt" würde bedeuten, dass sie auch schneller war als die männliche Konkurrenz.

Comment: Weak vs. strong declination of adjectives.

Comment: This question will help you, just ignore the *Schäferhund*: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/13765/35111

Comment: The previous answer referred to does not help me. The answer to my question is, that in German there are "adjectival nouns", which I did not know. See https://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/AdjectivalNouns/AdjectivalNouns.html

Comment: Your dictionary should have told you as much. For instance, the online dictionary by PONS has *Deutsche(r), f(m), dekl wie adj*.

Comment: My problem was that I had never heard of anything like an "adjectival noun" and so could not recognize it from the scant notation in PONS. English has not such concept. The key to the German idea is that there is a hidden noun that is not explicitly there but that is represented by capitalizing and declining the adjective as if it were. As an English speaker it is necessary for me to fill in what is missing in order to make sense of the grammar.